# How to apply focus css for all drop downs?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have below class for all textboxes

```
textarea:focus,input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="password"]:focus
{
border-color:#BBBBBB;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #888;
border-color:#3C8CDD;
color: #063E61;
color: rgb(171, 171, 171);
color:#063E61;
border-color: #3C8CDD;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size: 10px;
font-size:normal;
}
```

Can i use this same css class for type dropdowns?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="EnqDDL" runat="server" TabIndex="1" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="dropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EnqDDL_SelectedIndexChanged" ValidationGroup="Save_Group">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: why not use your CssClass with :focus instead?

Comment: asp[CssClass="dropdown"] { *all styles* }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `asp:DropDownList` is rendered as a `select` in HTML.

So, to implement the focus CSS on all drop-downs, add the following to your CSS rules:

```css
select:focus{}
```

So your code becomes like so:

```css
textarea:focus,input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="password"]:focus,select:focus
{
    border-color:#BBBBBB;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #888;
    border-color:#3C8CDD;
    color: #063E61;
    color: rgb(171, 171, 171);
    color:#063E61;
    border-color: #3C8CDD;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-size:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
​select:focus {
    background-color:red;
}​
```

will be used for dropdown lists.

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/c8wjL/